# Kivy TextInput how to combine hint_text and focus

Tags: python, kivy

Hi i noticed that whenever you have the focus property of a textinput widget set to True,
the hint_text is not displayed when the textinput is actually in focus.
Please is there a way to combine them both, i.e the hint_text gets displayed even when the text input is in focus?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an issue with Kivy 1.9.1, where the hint text disappears as soon as the TextInput is focused. It has been fixed in the development branch, and now only disappears when there is content in the field.